# Android SDK is not listed in IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm trying to develop an Android app using intelliJ, I've downloaded and installed Android SDK, but I cannot add it.

I've set up the environment variable ANDROID_HOME, and set the "PATH" variable to where my android sdk is + "\platform-tools"  (i.e. .....\sdk\platform-tools),

But when I try to android SDK, it's not listed

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Did you install/activate the Android plugin?

Also your PATH and ANDROID_HOME should point to android sdk dir and not to platform-tools.

Answer (score 0):

You have Android Studio. Why would you bother to install Android SDK in intelliJ?
Android Studio has a purpose of existing. I dont event think it s possible to add android SDK to IntelliJ. Download Android Studio and stop bothering yourself. Google would have said to use to use IntelliJ with Android SDK if it was designed to work like this instead struggling to make a complete IDE.

Comment: It's possible. Why on Earth would somebody install a separate android studio when he develop native java apps and already has intellij installed.

Comment: And why Google created Android Studio if it was possible to use IntelliJ with Android SDK if it s the same thing?

Comment: Because Android Studio is a lightweight IntelliJ just for Android development, and this way they can provide an own IDE. Also they've added some features to android studio which is not necessarily available in the IntelliJ plugin.